# Contain absolute positioned div inside viewport

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a graphical canvas map with tooltips.
The thing is I am trying to show my tooltip (a absolute positioned div) inside the viewport.
I thought this was a simple thing to do but i cant figure it out.

[EDIT]

```css
#container {
    background:black;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
}

#tooltip {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-25px;
}
#tooltip1 {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    left:100%;
    margin-left:-25px;
}
#tooltip2 {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    left:100%;
    top: 25%;
    margin-left:-25px;
}
#tooltip3 {
    background:red;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    left:25%;
    top: 25%;
    margin-left:-25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="tooltip"></div>
    <div id="tooltip1"></div>
    <div id="tooltip2"></div>
    <div id="tooltip3"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/scfpfvgw/

As you can see #tooltip1 and #tooltip2 are going off screen, what I want to achieve is that the tooltips stay inside te viewport.

[/EDIT]

[EDIT]

```js
// Handle hovering over regions
jQuery( self.getCanvas() ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
    // Get right coords values on resize
    var canvashw = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    var scaleX = this.width / canvashw.width;
    var scaleY = this.height / canvashw.height;
    var cursor = self.getCursor(event);
    var scaledX = Math.round( ( event.clientX - canvashw.left ) * scaleX );
    var scaledY = Math.round( ( event.clientY - canvashw.top ) * scaleY );

    cursor.x = scaledX;
    cursor.y = scaledY;

    if (object = self.matchRegion(cursor)) {
     // TOOLTIP!
     jQuery('#Tooltip').css({
      'display': 'block',
      'top': cursor.y / scaleY,
      'left': cursor.x / scaleX
     }).html('<h1>' + object.title + '</h1><hr><br><div id="tooltipwrapper"><img src=' + object.image_link + ' width="200px"><br>Adres:' + object.address + ' <br>' + object.zip_city + '<br>Telefoon:' + object.telephone + '<br><br><a href=' + object.a_link + '>Ga naar ' + object.title + '</a></div><div id="tooltipwrapper">' + '<div class="mobilehide"><b>Openingstijden:</b><br><br>' + object.openinghours + '</div>' + '</div>');
    } else {
     // Verberg tooltip!
     jQuery('#Tooltip').css({'display': 'none'});
    }
});
```

Comment: Share your tried code snippet.

Comment: What plugin are you using for tooltip?

Comment: I don't use a plugin it's custom built @zer00ne

Comment: @FrankGroot May we see this JS? It's hard to predict a function's behavior if we don't see the code.

Comment: @zer00ne added part of the JS

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/scfpfvgw/1/

```
right:0;
```

When you want to position it to the right side you need to use right:0; instead of left: 100%; Left 100% will offset the element with 100%, and that is not what you want if you will align it to the right side.

And also i did a reset for your body, and your container should have position relative.

Comment: Tnx for ur reply Bjorn,

But it isn't the answer I was looking for unfortunatly. 
I only used a container in my example, i can't use a container in combination with the html5 canvas. I use jquery to check if de mouse coords are inside the image. if the mouse coords are inside, then the tooltip is shown. I can't use right 0 because it will set all tooltips to right 0.

Comment: If you only can use the left property you will have a problem, because if you use left 100% the tooltip will go too far left.
Then you could use margin-left:-50px; but in that case left 0 will push the tooltip over the left edge.
You need padding of 25 on the container, thats the only way if you only can use the left property. :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a wrapper div with a padding of 25 pixels, assuming that your tooltips are never wider than 50px.

So as you can see the tooltips are never going outside the box, unless the `margin-left` property are not for every div the same.

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 25px;
  background: black;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

#tooltip {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

#tooltip1 {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

#tooltip2 {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  left: 100%;
  top: 25%;
  margin-left: -25px;
}

#tooltip3 {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="tooltip"></div>
    <div id="tooltip1"></div>
    <div id="tooltip2"></div>
    <div id="tooltip3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello NiZa,

Tnx for ur reply, but this isn't what i'm looking for.

The tooltips are shown on top of a html5 canvas. (I only used a container in my example, i can't use a container in combination with the canvas.) 

The fix of the margin-left isn't quite a good one if you think about coordinates, in this case all of the coordinates are 25px off too.

Comment: Can you explain me why a tooltip ever should going outside the viewport?

Comment: Why not doing `margin-left: -50px` in stead of `-25px`?